# Refresh <div> element in a Django html template

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, ajax

How can I refresh an element within a Django HTML template

Example

```
 <div class="container" id="myForm">
        <form action="/cgi-bin/hello_get.cgi" method="get">
            Fill the Detail:
            <br/>

            <textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="description">{{ bar_codes }}
     </textarea>

            <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>
    </div>
```

I have  JavaScript code that tries to refresh the div element with id `myform`.

```
<script>
    var append_increment = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: {% url 'detect_barcodes' %},  // URL to your view that serves new info
            data: {'append_increment': append_increment}
        })
        .done(function(response) {
            $('#myForm').append(response);
            append_increment += 10;
        });
    }, 10000)
</script>
```

the variable `bar_codes` data gets being updated contantly. The data is not from an api but from a barcode scanner.

This is the view

```
def detect(request):
    stream = CameraStream()
    success, frame = stream.camera.read()
    if success:
        status = True
    else:
        status = False
    bar_codes = stream.used_codes
    print(bar_codes)
    return render(request, 'detect_barcodes/detect.html', context={'bar_codes': bar_codes, 'cam_status': status})
```

This is the url.py file

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.detect, name='detect_barcodes'),
    path('camera_feed', views.camera_feed, name='camera_feed'),
]
```

How am reading the data and storing it

class CameraStream:
used_codes = []
def **init**(self):
self.camera = cv2.VideoCapture(int(0))

```
def get_frames(self):
    used_codes = self.used_codes
    while True:
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        success, frame = self.camera.read()
        if not success:
            break
        else:
            ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)

            # Add text on top of the barcode if there is a barcode in the stream using opencv
            # convert camera frame to numpy array
            color_image = np.asanyarray(frame)


            # decode numpy array to check if there is a barcode in color_image
            if decode(color_image):
                for code in decode(color_image):
                    if code.data.decode('utf-8') not in used_codes:
                        print('Approved. You can enter!')
                        print(code.data.decode('utf-8'))
                        used_codes.append(code.data.decode('utf-8'))
                    elif code.data.decode('utf-8') in used_codes:
                        print('Sorry, this code has been already used!')
                    else:
                        pass
                    cv2.imshow('Testing-code-scan', frame)
                    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

return used_codes

Comment: instead of rendering template you can pass `JsonResponse` or `HttpResponse` and pass status in that and than access it in your `AJAX`  `.done(fucntion{})` like this `if(response.status){chenge data of tag}`

Comment: Hi @AnkitTiwari thank you for your response, am actually storing the data as a List in an Array and passing the data `context={'bar_codes': bar_codes,`

Comment: Did you get any response from backend when you call `AJAX`

Comment: Hi @AnkitTiwari I have no backend just saving data to a list from a barcode reader, have updated my code on how am doing it

Comment: Hello @arriff backend means server side script which is not visible to normal user in your backend is your python script

Comment: try to `console.log()` your response in `AJAX` and let me know what is the output

Comment: Nothing is returned on AJAX

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233251/discussion-between-ankit-tiwari-and-arriff).